# Coding a graph w/ Cardinal direction movement?

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph, graph-theory

Studying data structures, I've come across the graph data structure and I feel it fits my need to express the following image in code: [image: Labyrinth]

---

Essentially, I intend to create a travellable map, each "Location" is a node of the graph structure, and issued commands [North, East, West, South] allow the player to travel across each node. The red node represents the players starting location. My problem lies in the graph itself, because:

I do not know how to introduce the concept of the cardinal directions to, for example, an adjacency list that simply contains nodes without any idea of its cardinal placement, for example, node [0] could be connected to [0]->[4]->[8]->[3], but I wouldn't be able to know whether [4] is the result I want when i issue the north command.

A simple way of addressing these issue would be through the following linked list:

```
struct Area {
        int code;
        string title;
        Area *north;
        Area *east;
        Area *south;
        Area *west;
    };
    Area *Lookup;
```

Each node having its adjacent nodes manually defined, however, as this is for a data structures class(hashmap/map/vectors are unusable), I would have liked to have implemented it through the adjacencylist method (if it is even possible). Is this possible, if so, how would it be implemented?

Would an adjacency matrix be a better alternative?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your approach. You could implement adjacency lists by simply collecting all non-null pointers, if required. Don't forget to update those cardinal pointers if the graph shape ever changes!

Comment: Since this is a class project, i'm not sure if my method is a proper graph implementation. For an adj Matrix, I could simply read if the node is a one or not to pass I guess. The updating comment is a good point, if a section gets closed I'll need the nodes to reflect it.

Comment: A "proper graph implementation" only requires that you can retrieve all nodes and the edges for a given node (list or matrix does not matter, they are interchangeable). It does not care about which 'direction' the edges go to.